# Accessing functions in a highcharts click event in an ionic project

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic3

I'm trying to access some variables and functions within the point click event, but I can't get it to work because of scoping, I assume. I've tried defining a variable for the class so it's accessible, but that's not compatible with my other variable. Same goes for function.

**This is messy.** I need to clarify that userData is initialized as an array, but as each point is selected, it turns into an object because the select() function is called. This is because the chart data is not a copy of userData[] but is **is** userData[].

Alright, so I have a few functions here with different functionality.

**nextDay()** increases x value by 1 and selects the point

**variablePlus()** increases the y value(s) by 1

**dataUpdater()** updates the local y value to match the value in the userData list and displays the value on the HTML page.

**relevant code from chart.ts:**

```
export class ChartPage {

 private day = 0;
 private chart: any;
 public userData: any;
 private y: any;
 private static day: number; // Not used 

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  this.userData = [18,14,15,15,15,13,13,12,14,14,14,14,14,14,15];
  this.y = this.userData[this.day];

 }

 nextDay() {
  if (this.day == this.chart.series[3].data.length){
    return
  }
  else {
    this.day++;
    this.chart.series[3].data[this.day].select();
    this.dataUpdater();
    }
 }

 variablePlus() {
  this.y++;
  this.chart.series[3].data[this.day].update({
    y:this.y
  });
  console.log(this.y);
  this.dataUpdater();
 }

 dataUpdater() {
 this.y = this.userData[this.day].y;

 let dayText = document.querySelector('#dayNum');
 dayText.textContent = (this.chart.series[3].data[this.day].x) + 1;
 }


 // Chart constructed on load
 ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChartPage');
  this.chart = HighCharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            margin: [0,0,0,0]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Y data'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            // Defined a day-variable for the class cause of scoping
                            // Doesn't matter since variablePlus() still works off other variable
                            // ChartPage.day = this.category;
                            // this.series.data[ChartPage.day].select();
                            // want to run dataUpdater() and update local day value
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: this.typeData.name,
            data: this.typeData.data,
            color: 'blue'
        }, {
            name: this.otherData.name,
            data: this.otherData.data,
            color: 'orange'
        }, {
            name: 'Line attempt',
            data: [{x: 0, y: 16}, {x: 20, y: 16}],
            color: 'red'
        },{
            name: 'User defined',
            data: this.userData,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            color: 'green'
        }]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I encourage you to use `highcharts-angular` wrapper. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular.

> I'm trying to access some variables and functions within the point
>   click event

To access properties and methods from your component object you can follow this approach:

In the constructor save component reference which you will use later in the chart options object defined below it. You will also need to save chart reference to the component property because you use it in other methods like nextDay() for example (Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#chart-instance). Check demo I posted below.

**chart.component.html :**

```
<div>
  <highcharts-chart 
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
    [(update)]="updateFlag"
    [oneToOne]="oneToOneFlag"
    [runOutsideAngular]="runOutsideAngularFlag"
  ></highcharts-chart>
</div>
<button (click)="onNextDay()">Next point</button>
```

**chart.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  private Highcharts = Highcharts;
  private chartConstructor = 'chart';
  private updateFlag = false;
  private oneToOneFlag = true;
  private runOutsideAngular = false;
  private chartOptions: any;
  private chartCallback: any;
  private day = 0;
  private chart: any;
  private y: any = 0;
  public userData: any;

  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    self.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;
    };

    self.userData = [
      18, 14, 15, 15, 15, 13, 13, 12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15
    ];
    self.y = self.userData[self.day];

    self.chartOptions = {
      xAxis: {
        crosshair: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
          },
          point: {
            events: {
              click() {
                console.log(this);
                self.day = this.category;
                this.series.data[self.day].select();
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Line attempt',
        data: [
          {x: 0, y: 16},
          {x: 20, y: 16}
        ],
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        name: 'User defined',
        data: self.userData.slice(),
        allowPointSelect: true,
        color: 'green'
      }]
    };
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('updated');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  onNextDay() {
    if (this.day !== this.chart.series[1].data.length - 1) {
      this.day++;
      this.chart.series[1].data[this.day].select();
      this.dataUpdater();
    }
    console.log(this);
   }

  onVariablePlus() {

  }

  dataUpdater() {
    this.y = this.userData[this.day].y;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/p54w049677

Comment: I tried getting this to work, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do it your way in an ionic project. Really appreciate the answer though!